# What is an "operator chair"?

Tags: meaning

It appears that operator chairs are a kind of office chair, but I have not been able to find an explanation describing exactly what distinguishes an "operator" chair from any other kind.

Comment: More context please... Where did you see it?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy In a shop selling furniture. If you google "operator chair", it seems to be a common category.

Comment: A random hunch - Could it be a "{computer} operator chair"? Or perhaps a {store} operator chair? Because the images seem to suggest that these are kinds of chairs you'd find in an IT office or inside the rooms of company heads.

Comment: I'm guessing it goes back to the early days of telephones, when rows upon rows of telephone operators sat in the same place all day long, and would have needed comfortable chairs.

Comment: Pictures would help, of "operator chair" and those of any other kind.

Comment: I'd think first of the chair used by a crane operator, which shouldn't have arms, since arms would interfere with using the crane controls down at the operator's side.

Comment: Looking at chairs pictured on Google, it appears to be a basic office chair, only with a high back, presumably for use by someone who must sit for long periods at some sort of operator's console.  I'm not sure you'll find a "hard" definition of it, though, as such terms tend to be quite "squishy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding telephone operator chairs, these women were packed very close together in rows. The chairs had to swivel in order for them to get in and out past one another. How do I know? I just asked my mom who is eating breakfast beside me, and was an operator from '48 to '55. They had a back but no armrests.

Comment: It appears to be primarily a UK term. I don't think I've seen it in the U.S. or Canada.